# Как восстановить состояние ListView Flutter при возвращении

Tags: flutter, dart

Как восстановить состояние ListView Flutter при возвращении на этот ListView.

У меня есть ListView, он содержит список, я перехожу на другой экран, а когда возвращаюсь, список перешел в начальное состояние.

Comment: Что значит в начальное состояние? Добавьте примеры. В идеале, минимальный проект где воспроизводится ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, для того чтобы сохранить состояние списка, надо использовать ключ PageStorageKey.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
addWidgetToList();
return _formHomePage(key: "home");
}

Widget _formHomePage({String key}) {
return ListView.builder(
    key: PageStorageKey(key),
    addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: _listWidgets.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return _listWidgets[index];
    });
}
```